# What does "crude" mean in this context?

Tags: definitions

Taken from Ian Freshney's Culture of Animal Cells:

> The enzymes used most frequently for tissue disaggregation are
>   **crude** preparations of trypsin, collagenase, elastase, pronase, Dispase, DNase, and hyaluronidase...

What does ***crude*** mean in this context?

Answer (score 3):

In this context **crude** means *naturally occurring* or *unrefined*.

Purified trypsin alone, for example, is usually ineffective for tissue dissociation since it shows little selectivity for extracellular proteins.

Source: [Worthington Tissue Dissociation Guide](http://www.worthington-biochem.com/tissuedissociation/trypsin.html)